# Google Script: Can't hide cells in all the tabs/sheets

Tags: google-api, google-sheets

I have the script below. I started with wanting to hide cells (which have "x" in A:A) only for the sheet/tab "March", but I need to make it across all the tabs.

How can I do it? Thanks for help.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("March");
  var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();

  //show all the rows
  sheet.showRows(1, maxRows);

  //get data from clumn A
  var data = sheet.getRange('A:A').getValues();

  //iterate over all rows
  for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++){
    //compare first character, if asterisk, then hide row
    if(data[i][0].charAt(0) == 'x'){
      sheet.hideRows(i+1);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using getSheets() - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets

First encapsulate your hide cells funciton;

```
function hideCells(sheet)
{
    var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();

  //show all the rows
  sheet.showRows(1, maxRows);

  //get data from clumn A
  var data = sheet.getRange('A:A').getValues();

  //iterate over all rows
  for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++){
    //compare first character, if asterisk, then hide row
    if(data[i][0].charAt(0) == 'x'){
      sheet.hideRows(i+1);
    }
}
```

Then run it on all the sheets:

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();

  for(var i=0; i< sheets.length; i++){

      hideCells(sheets[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: my bad, actually for functions we don't explicit the type. I've already corrected the code above.

Comment: btw. where did you learn this stuff? It seems so much harder than CSS/HTML.

Comment: you're welcome. I've learned from de oficial apps script documents. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview 
apps script is based on javascript, so it helps if you know a bit of javascript. besides, I don't have much experience on this, I credit the documents - easy to use and learn from. would you mind marking the response as answered? tks.